# What is dynamic programming? (in solving technique)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a problem to solve like this.

there is time interval, and each time interval can do work once. (I called this, 'task')

if there (4, 8), (1, 3), (8, 10), (0, 3), (6, 8) time interval and each interval means (start time, deadline).

this is one case idle time is three (an idle time is between tasks)

[image]

But I want to minimize idle time

[image]

How to solve these like problem by problem solving?
my friend suggests 'dynamic programming' which is one of problem solving technique, I don't know what it is.
Please help me, what is dynamic programming and examples by this problem.

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: LMGTFY: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: Chapter 6 of Algorithms by Dasgupta, Papadimitriou, and Vazirani is a good introduction to DP: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms.html

Comment: Do you mean that during each time interval, only one task can be done? In your picture tasks are being done concurrently.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1065433/387852)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good examples, articles, books for understanding dynamic programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278188/good-examples-articles-books-for-understanding-dynamic-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your friend means to find T1, T2, etc. with idle time in between and try to shorten this? In general dp means to eliminate variables that are unecessary for the solution thus speed up the overall compute time. Here is a good link: [difference between back tracking and Dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592943/difference-between-back-tracking-and-dynamic-programming)