# What is difference between backtracking and recursion

Tags: algorithm

I am new in backtracking algorithm. I am confused about difference between backtracking and recursion. I think for implementation of backtracking and other algorithm like as dynamic programming we use recursion. If there have any difference please leave your answer.

Comment: Recursion simply means calling a function from within itself. It may or may not involve backtracking.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java, C++, C, or C++11.  Please don't apply irrelevant tags to your questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about conceptual algorithm help and is not language specific, and should probably be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592943/difference-between-back-tracking-and-dynamic-programming

Answer (score 5):

*Backtracking* is an approach to solve certain kind of problems (From Bottom - to -Top). Common examples would be  : N-Queens, Sudoku etc.   *Recursion* is used to implement an algorithm that *backtracks*.